# MySQL Adding an index to table only with distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that looks like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e39c3e/1

My goal is to have the SID look like the Name + a index.
So when I `select * from Person` it should have an output of:

```
Name        SID
Bruno       Bruno1
Carl        Carl2
Carl        Carl2
Danielle    Danielle3
```

I've tried making another column with the indexes using auto_increment but of course that won't work the way I would like to.

Comment: What's the point of this? All copies of the name have the same index, so they're equivalent.

Comment: The unique indexes aren't really unique.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question, you are right the index are not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a subquery that assigns an incrementing number to each distinct name. Join that with the table in an `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE Person AS p1
JOIN (
    SELECT name, CONCAT(name, @index := @index + 1) AS newSID
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name
          FROM Person
          ORDER BY name) AS p2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @index := 0) AS var
) AS p2 ON p1.name = p2.name
SET p1.SID = p2.newSID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe804d/1)